# Compare POST Call JSON Data manually for validation with Mongoose Schema that is Stored in Database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

mongoose schema stored in database as JSON String :-

```
{
    name: {type: String, required: true}
    age: { type:Number, required: true}
}
```

---

POST call JSON data Example: -

```
{
    name: "Amit",
    age: 25
}
```

---

Schema With No Attribute (It will be used to store user data coming from client side): -

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({}, {strict: false});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

---

I want to validate the Data for every REST call, the schema that is stored in database is not static it can be changed over time. If validation is successful data will be saved with "User" Model. 
Is there any way to validate the data against the schema without Creating the Model? I am getting this error

> "OverwriteModelError: Cannot overwrite `cardDetails` model once
>   compiled."

[image]

Comment: Can you please show the full code? Probably the issue is persisting because you have already defined the scheme earlier somewhere and you are trying to define it again. The best way to define the schema once in global and use it at all

Comment: Yes you are right, but the problem is that in my case schema is not constant it will be changing over time, i have stored it in database ,  so i am creating the schema and model on the fly

Answer (score 0):

i resolved my issue with 1 line of code

```
delete mongoose.models['cardDetails'];
```

it will release the model from memory so that you can create it again.